# Second attempt of "¡Otro idioma! :)"

Tags: riddle, language, haiku

I'm going to try again with the "other languages" scheme. This time, I think the format makes sense.

> Right now you see me
>   Ahora no me miras
>   今、見ません

Who am I?

Rough translation (Still a valid haiku, yay!):

> Right now you see me
>   You do not see me right now (Spanish)
>   Now, you don't see me. (Japanese)

Hint:

> It's not a word. Well, it is a word, but it's a set of words. If you know what I mean...

Comment: No miras me ahorda => No me miras ahora. I believe.

Comment: @fffred rigth, but we use to say: "Ahora no me miras", the other wording just seems weird

Comment: The Spanish part should be "Ahora no me ves".

Comment: "mirar" means "look at", not "see".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> English

Because :

> Right now you see me --> this is English so you see English
>  No miras me ahorda --> you read and see Spanish, not English
>  今、見ません --> you read and see Japanese, not English

Hint :

> "English" is a word but it also represents all the english words

Comment: You did it! YAY!! (But explain the actual poem too.)

Answer (score 9):

Simply because you're:

> You ;)

Right now you see me

> See *you*.

No miras me ahorda

今、見ません

> Don't see *you* and those lines are saying exactly that in both Spanish and Japanese.

Hint

> *You* takes on a number of meanings: the word itself, your username and yourself.

Comment: I wouldn't be selfish enough to have that as an answer. lol

Comment: Maybe your *id* is controlling your *super-ego* ;)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Freudian analysis is based on [Id, ego and super-ego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id,_ego_and_super-ego).  So in this model your subconscious *id* could be manipulating your behavior unbeknownst to *You*.  Ok, I'll try to stop the joking about it...

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer

> me

Right now you see me

> I see "me", it's on the right

No miras me ahorda

> I see "me" but it's not on the right

今、見ません

> Now I don't see "me"

Comment: Nice reasoning about "right" and "me"! However, that is not the answer either.

Comment: The second (non-comma) character in Japanese is "mi", pronounced the same. ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> A statement in a West Germanic language?

Comment: Well, "me" is an English and Spanish word, but you're on the right track!

Comment: @You changed it slightly

Comment: Closer. Or farther, depending on the perspective. At least now its one and multiple words.